# Github Dismiss Stale approvals and rebasing

Tags: github

we want to turn on the "Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed" setting in Github, but don't want this setting to be activated when an Engineer performs a git rebase. Is this an option?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not an option.  There is no way for GitHub (or Git) to intrinsically know what a force-push contains or how it was performed.  Moreover, a rebase may necessitate resolving conflicts, which would necessarily result in a change to the diff before and afterwards.

Comment: You can absolutely know this. Simply diff the diffs (for example, using git range-diff). Because a rebase is simply replaying a diff onto a new base, if the diff of diffs is empty, you know it's just a rebase (or the moral equivalent). If merge conflicts were resolved, you will see that in the diff of diffs.

Comment: That approach works for some cases, but not all cases.  For example, differences in context will break that approach; there are also other, more complicated situations to consider.  It can be done easily in some cases, but not all cases, and it would be a poor user experience and drive lots of questions to have it magically work in some cases and not others.